# Using HttpClient to GET

Tags: c#, httpclient, webclient

So, because `HttpClient` is "better," I need to convert `WebClient` to `HttpClient`, but it just doesn't work as expected. The following function uses `WebClient` and works like a charm.

```
private static void Authenticate()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Authenticating . . .");
    var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthNClientId"];
    var uri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthNUri"];
    var userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthNUserName"];
    var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthNPassword"];

    var client = new WebClient();
    string formData = $"client_id={clientId}&grant_type=password&username={userName}&password={password}";
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var response = client.UploadString($"{uri}", formData);
    dynamic authResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
    _accessToken = authResult.access_token;
    if (_accessToken == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Unable to authenticate. Check your configuration file <appSettings>.");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Authenticated.");
}
```

This code, on the other hand, returns a `BadRequest` response code.

```
static async Task<string> GetAuthenticationToken()
{
    string token = string.Empty;

    var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthNClientId"];
    var uri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthNUri"];
    var userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthNUserName"];
    var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthNPassword"];

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myurl.com/oauth2/token");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var path = $"client_id={clientId}&grant_type=password&username={userName}&password={password}";
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"https://myurl.com/oauth2/token?{path}");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("success");
        token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    else { Console.WriteLine($"failure: {response.StatusCode}"); }
    return token;
}
```

You can see that I've tried it a couple of ways, including setting the client `BaseAddress` as well as just try to pass the url into the `GetAsync` method.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: In the `HttpClient` code, you don't show `client` being initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UploadString` is a `POST` method in the first example. In the second example a `GET` method is being done.

```
static async Task<string> GetAuthenticationTokenAsync() {
    string token = string.Empty;

    var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthNClientId"];
    var uri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthNUri"];
    var userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthNUserName"];
    var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthNPassword"];

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

    var nameValueCollection = new Distionary<string, string>() {
        { "client_id", clientId },
        { "grant_type", "password" },
        { "username", userName },
        { "password", password },
    };
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(nameValueCollection);
    var response = await client.PostAsync("", content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        Console.WriteLine("success");
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        dynamic authResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        token = authResult.access_token;
    }
    else { Console.WriteLine($"failure: {response.StatusCode}"); }
    return token;
}
```